# Reciprocal Rule of Integration with regards to $\Delta y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this following differential equation.

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = ky $$

During solving the indefinite integral:

$$ \int \dfrac{\Delta y}{y}$$

Part of one side of an equation like

$$ \int \dfrac{dy}{y} = \int k \cdot dx$$

difference symbol changed here on purpose. However, I'm having issues here, because once intergrated I'm being left with the $\Delta y$ or $dy$

$$ \Delta y \cdot \ln(|y|) + C$$

From website math is fun. They are left with $\ln|y| +C$.

What makes the difference act differently here. A very small value contained in the difference is going to turn any constant or initial value into mostly nothing.

Comment: What is $\Delta y$?

Comment: @Gary I've updated the question

Comment: dy or $\Delta y$ represents the change in y value ie $y(i) - y(i+n)$ where n is the size of the partition of the sum @Gary

Comment: "because once intergrated I'm being left with the Δ or "

Why are you left with these?  The integral of $\frac{dy}{y}$ is just $\ln(|y|) + C$ (I would actually argue that it is just $\ln(y) + C$ but that's a different issue).

Comment: @johnnyb must I first not convert the integral to $ \Delta y \int \dfrac{1}{y} = \int k \cdot \Delta x $ to be able to use the reciprocal rule of integration. dy != 1 it would be more like $0.0...1$ changing with the partition size

Comment: How can I integrate with out the dx part of $\int f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x$

Comment: @Gary dy represents a function that returns the difference of y at an x and x + partition size

Comment: @pepsi-maniac: The expression $\int \frac{1}{y}$ makes no sense. You need to have $\int  \frac{1}{y} dy$ in order to get $\ln|y|+C$.

Comment: @HansLundmark with respect to dy was implied. I would still get $\Delta y \cdot \ln|y| + C$

Comment: No, $\int \frac{1}{y} dy = \ln |y| + C$, since $\frac{d}{dy} \ln |y| = \frac{1}{y}$. Why do you think that this $\Delta y$ factor (whatever that's supposed to mean) shows up?

Comment: Because I transform $\frac{dy}{y}$ to $dy \cdot \frac{1}{y}$ before applying multiplication by constant and the reciprocal rule of intergration @HansLundmark

Comment: *What* rule? And multiplication by *what* constant? The rule for integrating $1/y$ with respect to $y$ is that you get $\ln |y|$, and that's all there is to it.

Comment: @HansLundmark arr, well, delta y isn't a constant, ok. But its still a term. Would the separation by parts work here. Or I"m just unsure where this term comes and goes

Comment: Nothing you're saying makes any sense to me at all. I honestly have no idea what exactly it is that you're misunderstanding, so I have nothing more to add in this discussion. But perhaps someone else will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to propose an answer based on what I *think* the OP's actual issue is, though it is still unclear.

When integrating, there is actually no preference for the $dx$ term.  You can integrate any variable.  What matters is not the variable but the *rule*.  This is why most calculus textbooks give the rules in terms of $u$ - it doesn't presume any particular variable you are likely to be using as special.

If you integrate $y' = 2x$, then you may have been taught to only integrate the right-hand side, and to treat it like $\int 2x$.  However, you are in fact integrating both sides.  The actual sequence of operations is:

$$
y' = 2x \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x \\
dy = 2x\, dx \\
\int dy = \int 2x\, dx \\
y + C_1 = x^2 + C_2 \\
y = x^2 + C_2 - C_1 \\
y = x^2 + C
$$

Note that the integration happened on both sides.  It's just on the left-hand side we were integrating a simple formula - $dy$.  However, we could have just as easily have integrated a more complex formula.  For instance, if we have $y' = \frac{x}{y}$, you can solve it like this:

$$
y' = \frac{x}{y} \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x}{y} \\
y\, dy = x\, dx \\
\int y\, dy = \int x\, dx 
$$
Here, note that both *forms* are the same, but they utilize different variables.  That's not a problem!  As long as the form is followed, the variable doesn't matter (note, though, that it *does* matter that both the $y$ and the $dy$ match - that's part of the form).  So, integrating this would give us:

$$
\frac{y^2}{2} + C_1 = \frac{x^2}{2} + C_2 \\
y^2 + 2\,C_1 = x^2 + 2\,C_2 \\
y^2 = x^2 + 2\,C_2 - 2\,C_1 \\
y^2 = x^2 + C
$$

So, as you can see, you can integrate complicated formulas for any variable, as long as it follows the form.  The variable does not have to be of $x$.  So, in your case, you had $\int\frac{dy}{y}$.  This integrates to $\ln(|y|) + C$.  Neither $x$ nor $dx$ need to be present to perform the integration.

So, in general, you are always actually integrating the $y$ side, it's just that usually the left-hand side is an integral of $\int dy \to y + C$, and even the $C$ is usually just implicitly moved over to the right-hand side.